# What is the meaning of where is it gone/going?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conversation

I was sitting next to a guy. He dropped something on the ground by accident. Then he said to himslef "where is it gone/going?" or at least that was what I heard. Does this sentence ,if I got it correctly, mean where is my thing?
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: This question may be better suited on [ell.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that he said "Where's it gone?" [= "Where has it gone?"] -- in other words, "Where has it disappeared to?"